# apex5.0, call webservice to populate data in form

Tags: oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

Is there a way in apex5.0, to call a webservice and output the details in a form.

webservice
input parameter : employee_no

output
employee_name
employee_address
employee_phn
employee_hire_date

And the fields in the form should be populated when the employee no is entered.

Any idea.. how to do that?

Answer (score 2):

Add Web Service References from Shared Components --> Data References. APEX engine can use Web Service References to access a Web service across the network.

Also, check out **APEX_WEB_SERVICE** API. It enables you to integrate other systems with APEX by allowing you to interact with Web services anywhere you can use PL/SQL in your application. The API contains procedures and functions to call both SOAP and RESTful style Web services.

Link to documentation --> https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/AEAPI/apex_web_service.htm#AEAPI537

There is pre-built packaged application that is shipped with APEX 5, it is called "Sample REST Services" which showcases how to access external REST services from Oracle Application Express pages